# Converting curl command to Laravel Http

Tags: laravel, curl, php-curl

I'm stuck while converting a curl command to Laravel Http facade command.

```
curl -i --upload-file ~/Desktop/Myimage.jpg -H 'Authorization: Bearer Redacted' "https://www.linkedin.com/dms-uploads/C5622AQHdBDflPp0pEg/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&sync=1&v=beta&ut=1lrKqjt4fYuqw1"
```

I tried the Laravel command as below but the server complains `400 Bad Request`

```
Http::attach("file_display_name", file_get_contents("path_to_file"), "file_name_with_extension")
->withHeaders([
    "Authorization" => "Bearer Redacted"
])
->put("https://www.linkedin.com/dms-uploads/C5622AQHdBDflPp0pEg/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&sync=1&v=beta&ut=1lrKqjt4fYuqw1");
```

Appreciate your help with identifying what I'm doing wrong.

PS: Curl command works successfully.

Edit: Tried Postman as John Lobo suggested.

I've set the request method as PUT and have used form-data to set the file. I'm not sure if this is the proper way of doing it though as I'm getting `400 Bad Request` with this approach as well. Nothing else on the response body.

[image]

Comment: check what response you get from http client

Comment: not much info other than `400 Bad Request`. I'm more interested in if I've converted the --upload-file to attach correctly.

Comment: then try with postman once

Comment: @JohnLobo - I've tried Postman as suggested but still no luck. I've updated the question with info from that attempt. Maybe you I'm doing something wrong with how I'm attaching the file in Postman as opposed to curl --upload-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research (thanks to ChatGPT), I found my mistake.

I wasn't setting the key for the file correctly. The key for the file needs to be `file` exactly. Then it works.

Updated Laravel code:

```
Http::attach("file", file_get_contents("path_to_file"), "file_name_with_extension")
->withHeaders([
    "Authorization" => "Bearer Redacted"
])
->put("https://www.linkedin.com/dms-uploads/C5622AQHdBDflPp0pEg/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&sync=1&v=beta&ut=1lrKqjt4fYuqw1");
```